# git request-pull: how do you apply a git request-pull email to your repo

Tags: git

I like the fact that git will allow you to create a request-pull to send to kernel.org or whomever to pull your changes, but my question is what command do you use with git to actually act on the pull request the same way that 'git am ' works.

It looks like you can create a request-pull email but there is no way to actually apply it I can find in any online git documentation.  Does it require a separate script to process what's in the request-pull email to actually pull the changes into you local repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in "[Distributed Git - Contributing to a Project](https://git-scm.com/book/ch5-2.html#Forked-Public-Project)":

> The output can be sent to the maintainer – it tells them where the work was branched from, summarizes the commits, and tells where to pull this work from.

It means the maintainer can add a remote referencing that contributing repo url, fetch and merge

```
 git remote add contribution /url/contributing/repo
 git fetch contribution
 git merge contribution/abranch
```

(Here is an example of a [good request-pull](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.kernel/w957vpu3PPU), [according to Linus Torvalds](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/17#issuecomment-5663780))

Comment: Sadly, the answer to my question appears to be NO, there is no way to instruct git to act on a request-pull directly without the receiver having to stand on his head, and use a bunch of awkward commands to get the changes in.  git request-pull is therefore is not fully implemented in git, is completely useless for use in an automated build setup.